Replace icons with text or add text to icons in Ultimate Member wordpress plugin
How can I add text the icons on the account page which is using woocommerce plugin? It looks like the 1st image and I want it to look like the 2nd image below.
How it looks now:

How I want it to look like:

Trying to add text to icons menu in Ultimate Member wordpress plugin using the Woocoemmerce plugin to get member details, shipping address, purchased products etc.
Unable to add the text next to the icons
